# Как Linux поможет для создания VPS?

Tags: vps, linux

Мне нужно, чтобы торговая платформа МТ-4 работала круглосуточно. Я работаю на рынке Форекс. Мне нужен VPS. Как может помочь Linux для решения этого вопроса и что для этого нужно сделать в первую очередь?

Answer (score 3):

VPS\VDS - это виртуальный сервер. МОгу предположить, что купив такой сервер, и поставив на него Windows+MT4 (понятия не имею, что это, но уверен что это под винду). Вы получите комп гдето там, независимо от вас работающий почти всегда.

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже работаю на рынке Форекс и мне не понятно, зачем это нужно? Каждый раз загружая терминал, Вы обновляете графики. Торговые роботы работают независимо от того включен терминал или нет.